# Fix rotation orientation using sidewaystable

Tags: tables, rotating, sidewaystable

I am trying to rotate two tables using sidewaystable but one of them was rotated clockwise while the other was rotated counterclockwise. Both of them use the same code, only the cell values are different. How do I fix this?

This is the code for both tables:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
      & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{FFF-W}             & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{FFF-A}                     & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{FFF-R}                     \\ \hline
Inst. & Obj. & Desp. (\%) & $\sigma$      & Tempo & Obj. & Desp. (\%) & $\sigma$      & Tempo & Obj. & Desp. (\%) & $\sigma$      & Tempo \\ \hline
A1    & 1578     & 2.86       & 0             & 0.05  & 1578     & 2.86       & 0             & 0.05  & 1578     & 2.86       & 0             & 0.05  \\
A2    & 27990    & 13.13      & 0             & 0.05  & 27916    & 12.89      & 0             & 0.05  & 41613    & 42.23      & 5.3           & 0.05  \\
A3    & 17933    & 27.29      & 0             & 0.05  & 17788    & 26.48      & 0             & 0.05  & 21759    & 39.5       & 5.25          & 0.05  \\
A4    & 17933    & 27.29      & 0             & 0.05  & 17788    & 26.48      & 0             & 0.05  & 22342    & 38.21      & 4.94          & 0.05  \\
A5    & 25648    & 26.75      & 0             & 0.05  & 23158    & 23.06      & 0             & 0.05  & 28616    & 36.86      & 3.1           & 0.05  \\
A6    & 19684    & 25.87      & 0             & 0.05  & 19684    & 25.87      & 0             & 0.05  & 23381    & 38.61      & 5.02          & 0.05  \\
A7    & 32034    & 28.24      & 0             & 0.05  & 32145    & 28.55      & 0             & 0.05  & 38003    & 38.09      & 3.67          & 0.05  \\
A8    & 61964    & 28.73      & 0             & 0.05  & 59812    & 28.01      & 0             & 0.05  & 68575    & 35.86      & 2.05          & 0.05  \\
A9    & 23465    & 39.52      & 0             & 0.05  & 23465    & 39.52      & 0             & 0.05  & 26058    & 41.4       & 3.04          & 0.05  \\
A10   & 29015    & 22.88      & 0             & 0.05  & 32783    & 29.54      & 0             & 0.05  & 38556    & 39.96      & 3.41          & 0.05  \\
A11   & 26379    & 21.01      & 0             & 0.05  & 28519    & 28.14      & 0             & 0.05  & 33075    & 36.38      & 4.18          & 0.05  \\
A12   & 15015    & 32.91      & 0             & 0.05  & 16342    & 40.29      & 0             & 0.05  & 19038    & 43.49      & 5.72          & 0.05  \\
A13   & 80070    & 16.18      & 0             & 0.05  & 80070    & 16.18      & 0             & 0.05  & 97801    & 30.52      & 1.79          & 0.05  \\
A14   & 87501    & 18.87      & 0             & 0.05  & 86893    & 18.2       & 0             & 0.05  & 107166   & 33.47      & 1.77          & 0.05  \\
A15   & 94424    & 20.92      & 0             & 0.05  & 95616    & 22.16      & 0             & 0.05  & 111726   & 32.44      & 1.75          & 0.05  \\
A16   & 15980    & 24.18      & 0             & 0.05  & 16817    & 28.83      & 0             & 0.05  & 20500    & 36.64      & 4.53          & 0.05  \\
A17   & 11357    & 43.7       & 0             & 0.05  & 13535    & 41.23      & 0             & 0.05  & 12772    & 42.59      & 1.23          & 0.05  \\
A18   & 26261    & 24.94      & 0             & 0.05  & 26261    & 24.94      & 0             & 0.05  & 34106    & 40.85      & 3.82          & 0.05  \\
A19   & 19636    & 28.54      & 0             & 0.05  & 19636    & 28.54      & 0             & 0.05  & 23245    & 40.33      & 4.11          & 0.05  \\
A20   & 9963     & 44.84      & 0             & 0.05  & 9963     & 44.84      & 0             & 0.05  & 10256    & 44.11      & 10.37         & 0.05  \\ \hline
Média      &          & 25.9325    &               & 0.05  &          & 26.8305    &               & 0.05  &          & 36.72      &               & 0.05 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:1}
\caption{Teste}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
      & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{SHP-W}             & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{SHP-A}                     & \multicolumn{5}{|c}{SHP-R}                     \\ \hline
Inst. & H1   & Obj. & Desp. (\%) & $\sigma$ & Tempo & H1   & Obj. & Desp. (\%) & $\sigma$ & Tempo & H1   & Obj. & Desp. (\%) & $\sigma$ & Tempo \\ \hline
A1  & 1600 & 1578     & 2.86       & 0             & 0.05  & 1600 & 1578     & 2.86       & 0             & 0.05  & 1600 & 1578     & 2.86       & 0             & 0.05  \\
A2  & 3600 & 36838    & 30.45      & 0             & 0.05  & 3500 & 36345    & 29.27      & 0             & 0.05  & 3500 & 46208    & 45.21      & 5.73          & 0.05  \\
A3  & 2300 & 21031    & 33.38      & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 21149    & 33.87      & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 22542    & 38.58      & 3.4           & 0.05  \\
A4  & 2300 & 21031    & 33.38      & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 21149    & 33.87      & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 22568    & 39.23      & 2.82          & 0.05  \\
A5  & 2400 & 27646    & 33.41      & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 28080    & 34.86      & 0             & 0.05  & 2400 & 30559    & 39.05      & 2.55          & 0.05  \\
A6  & 2200 & 17877    & 24.46      & 0             & 0.05  & 2200 & 17877    & 24.46      & 0             & 0.05  & 2200 & 22771    & 36.12      & 4.74          & 0.05  \\
A7  & 3000 & 36821    & 35.6       & 0             & 0.05  & 3200 & 36821    & 35.6       & 0             & 0.05  & 3000 & 40495    & 40.03      & 3.47          & 0.05  \\
A8  & 2900 & 68271    & 35.09      & 0             & 0.05  & 3000 & 69551    & 36.87      & 0             & 0.05  & 2900 & 71167    & 38.59      & 1.95          & 0.05  \\
A9  & 2300 & 22055    & 33.64      & 0             & 0.05  & 2400 & 22428    & 35.2       & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 26597    & 42.77      & 3.78          & 0.05  \\
A10 & 2800 & 35688    & 37.61      & 0             & 0.05  & 2800 & 37189    & 35.81      & 0             & 0.05  & 2800 & 40687    & 43.09      & 3.4           & 0.05  \\
A11 & 2300 & 29579    & 31.68      & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 29909    & 32.78      & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 32907    & 35.64      & 3.48          & 0.05  \\
A12 & 2600 & 15174    & 33.8       & 0             & 0.05  & 2600 & 15174    & 33.8       & 0             & 0.05  & 2600 & 17818    & 42.94      & 5.12          & 0.05  \\
A13 & 2200 & 98070    & 30.97      & 0             & 0.05  & 2200 & 98070    & 30.97      & 0             & 0.05  & 2200 & 105113   & 35.95      & 1.36          & 0.05  \\
A14 & 2200 & 101159   & 30.04      & 0             & 0.05  & 2200 & 101474   & 30.35      & 0             & 0.05  & 2200 & 108576   & 34.35      & 1.2           & 0.05  \\
A15 & 2100 & 113221   & 34.11      & 0             & 0.05  & 2400 & 111374   & 32.49      & 0             & 0.05  & 2100 & 116457   & 35.33      & 1.21          & 0.05  \\
A16 & 2500 & 16495    & 27.04      & 0             & 0.05  & 2500 & 19002    & 30.73      & 0             & 0.05  & 2500 & 20313    & 37.29      & 4.14          & 0.05  \\
A17 & 2300 & 11357    & 43.7       & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 14287    & 45.41      & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 12529    & 44.38      & 0.84          & 0.05  \\
A18 & 2300 & 28522    & 32.48      & 0             & 0.05  & 2600 & 28302    & 31.74      & 0             & 0.05  & 2300 & 33252    & 40.15      & 5.28          & 0.05  \\
A19 & 2600 & 20182    & 30.81      & 0             & 0.05  & 2600 & 20182    & 30.81      & 0             & 0.05  & 2600 & 23515    & 40.34      & 4.74          & 0.05  \\
A20 & 3200 & 8871     & 35.74      & 0             & 0.05  & 3200 & 8871     & 35.74      & 0             & 0.05  & 3200 & 8724     & 34.51      & 3.52          & 0.05  \\ \hline
Média  &   &          & 31.5125    &               & 0.05  &      &          & 31.8745    &               & 0.05  &      &          & 37.3205    &               & 0.05 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:2}
\caption{Teste}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and whether one-sided or two-sided page formatting is in force.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430516/one-table-rotated-correctly-problem-with-another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An excerpt from page 2 of the user guide of the `rotating` package:

> [image]

Your write-up strongly suggests that your document employs the `twoside` document class option, either directly or indirectly. If that's the case, load the `rotating` package

- with the option `figuresleft` if you want `sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure` environments to be rotated uniformly clockwise; or, conversely,
- with the option `figuresright` if you want `sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure` environments to be rotated uniformly counterclockwise.

---

*Addendum*: In addition to loading the `rotating` package with either `figuresright` or `figuresleft`, you may want to apply some edits to your tables to make them visually more attractive. For instance, you might (a) eliminate all vertical rules -- trust me, they're not needed; (b) use the macros of the `booktabs` package -- such as `\toprule`, `\cmidrule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\addlinespace` -- instead of LaTeX's basic `\hline` directive; and (c) align the numbers on their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers.

It may seem like a lot of work, at first, to apply these visual improvements. However, the potential benefits are even more substantial: Readers are usually quite willing to take a closer look and absorb the contents of well-designed and -formatted tables. The same cannot be said for haphazardly produced tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page paramerters appropriately
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, etc
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
% create 2 column types based on the 'S' column type:
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\newcolumntype{U}[1]{S[table-format=#1,
                       round-mode=places, % apply rounding automatically
                       round-precision=2]}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l T{5.0} U{2.2} T{1.0} c
                      T{5.0} U{2.2} T{1.0} c
                      T{6.0} U{2.2} T{2.2} c @{}}
\toprule
Inst. & \multicolumn{4}{c}{FFF-W} 
      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{FFF-A} 
      & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{FFF-R} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
& {Obj.} & {Desp.\ (\%)} & {$\sigma$} & {Tempo}
& {Obj.} & {Desp.\ (\%)} & {$\sigma$} & {Tempo} 
& {Obj.} & {Desp.\ (\%)} & {$\sigma$} & {Tempo} \\ 
\midrule
A1  &  1578 &  2.86 & 0 & 0.05 &  1578 & 2.86  & 0 & 0.05 &  1578 & 2.86  & 0    & 0.05 \\
A2  & 27990 & 13.13 & 0 & 0.05 & 27916 & 12.89 & 0 & 0.05 & 41613 & 42.23 & 5.3  & 0.05 \\
A3  & 17933 & 27.29 & 0 & 0.05 & 17788 & 26.48 & 0 & 0.05 & 21759 & 39.5  & 5.25 & 0.05 \\
A4  & 17933 & 27.29 & 0 & 0.05 & 17788 & 26.48 & 0 & 0.05 & 22342 & 38.21 & 4.94 & 0.05 \\
A5  & 25648 & 26.75 & 0 & 0.05 & 23158 & 23.06 & 0 & 0.05 & 28616 & 36.86 & 3.1  & 0.05 \\ 
\addlinespace
A6  & 19684 & 25.87 & 0 & 0.05 & 19684 & 25.87 & 0 & 0.05 & 23381 & 38.61 & 5.02 & 0.05 \\
A7  & 32034 & 28.24 & 0 & 0.05 & 32145 & 28.55 & 0 & 0.05 & 38003 & 38.09 & 3.67 & 0.05 \\
A8  & 61964 & 28.73 & 0 & 0.05 & 59812 & 28.01 & 0 & 0.05 & 68575 & 35.86 & 2.05 & 0.05 \\
A9  & 23465 & 39.52 & 0 & 0.05 & 23465 & 39.52 & 0 & 0.05 & 26058 & 41.4  & 3.04 & 0.05 \\
A10 & 29015 & 22.88 & 0 & 0.05 & 32783 & 29.54 & 0 & 0.05 & 38556 & 39.96 & 3.41 & 0.05 \\ 
\addlinespace
A11 & 26379 & 21.01 & 0 & 0.05 & 28519 & 28.14 & 0 & 0.05 & 33075 & 36.38 & 4.18 & 0.05 \\
A12 & 15015 & 32.91 & 0 & 0.05 & 16342 & 40.29 & 0 & 0.05 & 19038 & 43.49 & 5.72 & 0.05 \\
A13 & 80070 & 16.18 & 0 & 0.05 & 80070 & 16.18 & 0 & 0.05 & 97801 & 30.52 & 1.79 & 0.05 \\
A14 & 87501 & 18.87 & 0 & 0.05 & 86893 & 18.2  & 0 & 0.05 & 107166& 33.47 & 1.77 & 0.05 \\
A15 & 94424 & 20.92 & 0 & 0.05 & 95616 & 22.16 & 0 & 0.05 & 111726& 32.44 & 1.75 & 0.05 \\ 
\addlinespace
A16 & 15980 & 24.18 & 0 & 0.05 & 16817 & 28.83 & 0 & 0.05 & 20500 & 36.64 & 4.53 & 0.05 \\
A17 & 11357 & 43.7  & 0 & 0.05 & 13535 & 41.23 & 0 & 0.05 & 12772 & 42.59 & 1.23 & 0.05 \\
A18 & 26261 & 24.94 & 0 & 0.05 & 26261 & 24.94 & 0 & 0.05 & 34106 & 40.85 & 3.82 & 0.05 \\
A19 & 19636 & 28.54 & 0 & 0.05 & 19636 & 28.54 & 0 & 0.05 & 23245 & 40.33 & 4.11 & 0.05 \\
A20 &  9963 & 44.84 & 0 & 0.05 &  9963 & 44.84 & 0 & 0.05 & 10256 & 44.11 & 10.37& 0.05 \\ 
\midrule
Média & & 25.9325 & & 0.05 & & 26.8305 & & 0.05 & & 36.72 & & 0.05 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:1}
\caption{Teste}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c T{6.0} U{2.2} T{1.0} c
                      c T{6.0} U{2.2} T{1.0} c
                      c T{6.0} U{2.2} T{1.2} c @{}}
\toprule
Inst. & \multicolumn{5}{c}{SHP-W}
      & \multicolumn{5}{c}{SHP-A}
      & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{SHP-R} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11} \cmidrule(l){12-16}
& {H1}  & {Obj.} & {Desp.\ (\%)} & {$\sigma$} & {Tempo} 
& {H1}  & {Obj.} & {Desp.\ (\%)} & {$\sigma$} & {Tempo} 
& {H1}  & {Obj.} & {Desp.\ (\%)} & {$\sigma$} & {Tempo} \\
\midrule
A1  & 1600 &  1578 &  2.86 & 0 & 0.05 & 1600 &  1578 &  2.86 & 0 & 0.05 & 1600 &  1578 & 2.86  & 0    & 0.05 \\
A2  & 3600 & 36838 & 30.45 & 0 & 0.05 & 3500 & 36345 & 29.27 & 0 & 0.05 & 3500 & 46208 & 45.21 & 5.73 & 0.05 \\
A3  & 2300 & 21031 & 33.38 & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 21149 & 33.87 & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 22542 & 38.58 & 3.4  & 0.05 \\
A4  & 2300 & 21031 & 33.38 & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 21149 & 33.87 & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 22568 & 39.23 & 2.82 & 0.05 \\
A5  & 2400 & 27646 & 33.41 & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 28080 & 34.86 & 0 & 0.05 & 2400 & 30559 & 39.05 & 2.55 & 0.05 \\ 
\addlinespace
A6  & 2200 & 17877 & 24.46 & 0 & 0.05 & 2200 & 17877 & 24.46 & 0 & 0.05 & 2200 & 22771 & 36.12 & 4.74 & 0.05 \\
A7  & 3000 & 36821 & 35.6  & 0 & 0.05 & 3200 & 36821 & 35.6  & 0 & 0.05 & 3000 & 40495 & 40.03 & 3.47 & 0.05 \\
A8  & 2900 & 68271 & 35.09 & 0 & 0.05 & 3000 & 69551 & 36.87 & 0 & 0.05 & 2900 & 71167 & 38.59 & 1.95 & 0.05 \\
A9  & 2300 & 22055 & 33.64 & 0 & 0.05 & 2400 & 22428 & 35.2  & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 26597 & 42.77 & 3.78 & 0.05 \\
A10 & 2800 & 35688 & 37.61 & 0 & 0.05 & 2800 & 37189 & 35.81 & 0 & 0.05 & 2800 & 40687 & 43.09 & 3.4  & 0.05 \\  
\addlinespace
A11 & 2300 & 29579 & 31.68 & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 29909 & 32.78 & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 32907 & 35.64 & 3.48 & 0.05 \\
A12 & 2600 & 15174 & 33.8  & 0 & 0.05 & 2600 & 15174 & 33.8  & 0 & 0.05 & 2600 & 17818 & 42.94 & 5.12 & 0.05 \\
A13 & 2200 & 98070 & 30.97 & 0 & 0.05 & 2200 & 98070 & 30.97 & 0 & 0.05 & 2200 &105113 & 35.95 & 1.36 & 0.05 \\
A14 & 2200 &101159 & 30.04 & 0 & 0.05 & 2200 &101474 & 30.35 & 0 & 0.05 & 2200 &108576 & 34.35 & 1.2  & 0.05 \\
A15 & 2100 &113221 & 34.11 & 0 & 0.05 & 2400 &111374 & 32.49 & 0 & 0.05 & 2100 &116457 & 35.33 & 1.21 & 0.05 \\ 
\addlinespace
A16 & 2500 & 16495 & 27.04 & 0 & 0.05 & 2500 & 19002 & 30.73 & 0 & 0.05 & 2500 & 20313 & 37.29 & 4.14 & 0.05 \\
A17 & 2300 & 11357 & 43.7  & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 14287 & 45.41 & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 12529 & 44.38 & 0.84 & 0.05 \\
A18 & 2300 & 28522 & 32.48 & 0 & 0.05 & 2600 & 28302 & 31.74 & 0 & 0.05 & 2300 & 33252 & 40.15 & 5.28 & 0.05 \\
A19 & 2600 & 20182 & 30.81 & 0 & 0.05 & 2600 & 20182 & 30.81 & 0 & 0.05 & 2600 & 23515 & 40.34 & 4.74 & 0.05 \\
A20 & 3200 &  8871 & 35.74 & 0 & 0.05 & 3200 & 8871  & 35.74 & 0 & 0.05 & 3200 &  8724 & 34.51 & 3.52 & 0.05 \\ 
\midrule
Média & & & 31.5125 & & 0.05 & & & 31.8745 & & 0.05 & & & 37.3205 & & 0.05 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:2}
\caption{Teste}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's working the way I want now. I am pretty new with Latex so I had no idea about that.